# SCNNode material scale

Tags: scale, scenekit, scnnode

I have an SCNNode that has its geometry populated from a collada file (.dae) and displays correctly on screen. I can apply materials to the geometry easily enough, however I'd like to change the scale of the material.

I currently populate it with

```
nodeArray[0].geometry?.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents="wood.png"
```

but the scale of the material is too small. While I can edit the png in GIMP or something similar and import it as wood2.png is there any way I can set the material scale programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your UV snapshot in an image editing software like Photoshop, scale the wood texture in Photoshop over your UV's, then resave your PNG/JPG, move PNG/JPG back to Xcode

Answer (score 3):

what do you mean by "too small" ?

Geometries are made of different sources such as the vertices' positions, but also their texture coordinates. These texture coordinates (they belong in `[0,1]x[0,1]`) are specified per vertex and indicate where to look in the texture.

In your 3D modeler please check that your texture coordinates match what you want (i.e. they cover the whole image i.e. they go from `0` to `1` in very direction), and make sure that your image has no extra transparent margin or other wasted space.

You can have a look at `SCNMaterialProperty`'s `contentsTransform` property. But please check your model and texture before using it.

Comment: Hi Mnuages. Basically I have a model which I am mapping a wood texture over. On other larger models I can see the wood grain quite clearly, on this model it appears just as an average brown with no definition. I'm assuming my image is either too large or too small. I was hoping for a way to alter that scale do I can zoom in or out until the grain is visible again

Comment: have you verified your UVs ? Unless your object is really *really* small or your texture really *really* big. you should see details. I edited my answer with a mention to `SCNMaterialProperty.contentsTransform`

Comment: Will give that a try, thanks mate. The texture isn't specific to this model, just a generic image that I amusing on several similar models. I believe that this one particular model is a lot smaller than the others. Will confirm once I get back, on phone only at the moment.

Comment: Hadn't unwraped my UV object first, so my fault asked the incorrect question - however I still needed this as part of my solution.  Many thanks!